# Solve the given system of quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

> $$x^2 + xy + xz = 2$$
> $$y^2 + yz + xy = 3$$
> $$z^2 + zx + yz = 4$$

I tried solving it but i just ended up with
$$(x-y)(x+y+z) = -1$$
$$(y-z)(x+y+z) = -1$$
$$(x-z)(x+y+z) = -2$$

I'm not sure what to do. Any hints?

Comment: You can add $(x+y+z)^2=2+3+4=9$.

Answer (score 3):

Your equations are equivalent to $$x(x+y+z)=2,\quad y(x+y+z)=3,\quad z(x+y+z)=4.$$ Set $$x+y+z=t,$$ then $t^2=2+3+4=9$ and we have $t=\pm 3.$ Hence $$x=\pm\dfrac23,\qquad y=\pm 1,\qquad z=\pm\dfrac43.$$

Edit: Btw, here we hove only two solutions for the system.

Answer (score 2):

Take
$$ x = 2t \; , \; \;  y = 3 t \; , \; \;  z = 4t \; . \;$$
We know this is valid because $x+y+z$ must be nonzero, so too the individual letters, and
$$ \frac{y}{x} = \frac{3}{2} \; , \; \; \frac{z}{x} = \frac{4}{2} \; . $$Then $$ x+y+z = 9t  $$

Answer (score 1):

Solve first equation for $y$, substitute in the others, simplify...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by solving for (x+y+z) in all three original equations. Then you can compare the results to each other.